# Posting image to Facebook Page, iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, api

In my app, I'd like to be able to post to both a user's profile and to any of their pages. Posting to their profile is relatively simple and well-documented, however, I've found little in the realm of sample code as to posting an image to a Page. I have read [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/), however, it doesn't provide any examples as to how to do exactly what it says. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method Using Facebook Graph API

//facebook post a image on wall

```
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       userImgView.image, @"picture",
                                       nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                     andParams:params
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                   andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Won't this just post the image to the user's wall? If they have started a page for a band, or a celebrity, how do I post the image to *that* page?